# NativeScript: Fonts are not loading on Android

Tags: fonts, nativescript

I've got a problem with custom font in nativescript.
With this app, https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=y8q8C9, when I scan the QR code on my phone generated by the online editor, the nasalization font is displayed, everything works fine.
But when I download this app, and use "tns preview" on my local computer, the custom font is not loading.
It is the same with others projects.
My computer is on Windows 7, nodejs version is 12.16.2.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your fonts folder in your webpack.config.js file

```
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } }
```

Comment: Hey that was a good idea but it's already in my file. `new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            new nsWebpack.GenerateNativeScriptEntryPointsPlugin("bundle"),`

Comment: The default webpack config already takes care of fonts and images (PNG & JPG), unless you modified the original code, you won't hit this issue.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I don't understand why custom fonts are not loading...